# Using Raycaster with an Orthographic Camera

Tags: three.js

I am using orthographic camera for showing objects's dimension as they are. but the problem is that I cannot do intersection detection on this type of camera anymore. I searched on the net I found pickingray as a solution, but now it has been removed from r69. is there any possibility to get it worked wihtout pikcingray? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the new pattern to follow when using `Raycaster` with either a perspective camera or an orthographic camera:

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(); // create once
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(); // create once

...

mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;

raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, recursiveFlag );
```

three.js r.73

Comment: You need `(event.offsetX / rect.width) * 2 - 1` with `const rect = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect()` for correct operation when the entire window is not filled by the canvas or when devicePixelRatio is anything but 1.